# Play MMS stream with clear HTML5/JS

Tags: javascript, html, audio-streaming, mms

Is it possible to play `MMS` audio stream with `HTML5` / `JavaScript` in Google Chrome without any Windows Media Player object ?
I want to write a Google Chrome plugin that will allow playing that streams.

Comment: Nope - I figured it out that it is really impossible right now. We need flash plugin, etc to handle MMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. MMS is a proprietary Microsoft protocol.